# SumProduct Multiple columns using name for column index Vlookup across multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

I am trying to sum multiple columns from a table on a separate sheet using vlookup and matching the column index number with a name instead of the column number.  I can return a single result but can only seem to sum the product of the columns using the array {3,4,5} etc.

In one tab I have my data (simplified for this example)

[image: Data]

In another sheet I want to show the totals for Fred and Bob and Betty and Jane for each category.

[image: Result Table]

This returns a single result:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(($A2&""),'P&L by job'!$A$2:$E$4,MATCH($A$2,'P&L by job'!$A$1:$E$1,0),FALSE),0)
```

This formula will result in the sumproduct:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(($A2&""),'P&L by job'!$A$2:$E$4{2,3},FALSE)),0)
```

The issue is when an additional column is added, or the columns are in a different order each time I import the data across, I need to change the column index number in my spreadsheet.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Try peeling out *Bob, Fred, Betty* and *Jane* from the column headers.

```
=SUM(INDEX('P&L by job'!$A:$Z, MATCH($A2, 'P&L by job'!$A:$A, 0), MATCH(REPLACE(B$1, FIND(" and ", B$1), LEN(B$1), TEXT(,)), 'P&L by job'!$1:$1, 0)),
     INDEX('P&L by job'!$A:$Z, MATCH($A2, 'P&L by job'!$A:$A, 0), MATCH(REPLACE(B$1, 1, FIND(" and ", B$1)+4, TEXT(,)), 'P&L by job'!$1:$1, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: It's working +1 ☺

Comment: Thanks Jeeped - I will try this

Answer (score 0):

*Lookup formula wrapped with `SUMPRODUCT` and `nested IF` solves the issue:*

**Caveat:**

*Below shown method is best suitable to small data range like 8 to 10 columns, otherwise method/formula suggested by `@Jeeped` is better & a smart move.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Insert some helper data in Row 1 (`S1:X1`), you may extend them, if and when required.
- Write combination of names in Row 9 (`S9:U9`), remember you may change the order as your need.
- Formula in `S10`:

  ```
   =IFERROR(IF(S$1="A",SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP($R10,$R$3:$X$5,{6,7},FALSE)),IF(S$1="B",SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP($R10,$R$3:$X$5,{4,5},FALSE)),IF(S$1="C",SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP($R10,$R$3:$X$5,{2,3},FALSE)),""))),"")
  ```

**N.B.**

- *Fill formula across the range.*
- *You may adjust cell references & order of columns as needed.*